# HereMaps MapPolyline drawn over road names and signs

Tags: android, here-api

MapPolyline in HereMaps Android SDK is drawn top of the road names and signs thus covering them. Is there an option to draw it below?  I tried using zIndex but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [MapObject#setOverlayType](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapobject.html#topic-apiref__setoverlaytype-mapoverlaytype).